# Angular 2 How to make setter wait to input setter to complete

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i have a problem with that. In my component i have a inputt setter like this :

```
 @Input() set editStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.savedEditStatus = status;
    if (this.savedEditStatus === true && this.getTrigg === true) {

        this.getDataFromFlex("SHOWS_L").then((data: any) => {
            this.getTrigg = false;
            this.lengthDataOptions = data;
        })
    } else {
        this.getTrigg = true;
        this.lengthDataOptions = undefined;
    }

};
```

My problem is i get two edit status with value true and they are comming in the almost same time. So right now for this component in this case the getDataFromFlex function will be called two times. I don't want the second time call so i think the getTrigg(boolean) will be a solve. And its doesn't work. So i need a bit of help from you guys. 
The getTrigg is default on component initiation set for true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recomend you to use the [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) interface to do this kind of communication with external components. This will ensure that you have the expected value to do what you need after this value changes:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Input() savedEditStatus: boolean; // change to field not getter / setter

ngOnChanges(changes: { [propKey: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    if (changes['savedEditStatus'] && changes['savedEditStatus'].currentValue === true && 
        this.getTrigg === true) {
        this.getDataFromFlex("SHOWS_L").then((data: any) => {
            this.getTrigg = false;
            this.lengthDataOptions = data;
        })
    } else {
        this.getTrigg = true;
        this.lengthDataOptions = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you use === instead of simply "changes.savedEditStatus.currentValue", "this.getTrigg" ? And, ofcourse, in some cases(one single input) you could do smth like:
ngOnChanges ({ firstChange }: SimpleChanges){
  if(!firstChange) //  instead of use currentValue
}

And i recommend you to use es8 async await instead of ugly promises

Comment: @DenKerny this question is from 2017, angular and javascript have changed a lot in 3 years. === means type check in javascript

Comment: i took it into account, its es6(destructing)-es7(async functions) syntax, === - it's redundant just asked